# jQuery and Ajax combination confusion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am a new user and I need help with JQuery and Ajax. I am good at PHP only.

I have a HTML Page which has a newsletter signup section,

```
<h4>Newsletter</h4> 
<form id="main-news-contact-form" class="news-contact-form" name="news-contact-form" method="post" action="/scripts/xnews.php" role="form"> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email"/> 
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Go!</button>
         </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the relevant JQuery -

```
//newsletter form
var form = $('.news-contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
  $this = $(this);
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
  $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(15000).fadeOut();
  },'json');
  return false;
});
```

I have a php script, that reads the form data and saves the email address received in the database table, but for some reason the data (email address) is not being received by the PHP Code, the code below is executed.

```
if(empty($_POST["email"]))
{
  echo("failed");
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have a 'contact us' form, which is working absolutely fine, but I don't know why this newsletter form is not working with jquery.

I assure that all the javascript files are included in the html page, the php page is running absolutely fine, it does not return any php or mysql errors, I am setting JSON headers correctly, it's just that I am not getting the email address entered into the form. Earlier it was working but Ajax was not working, now I managed to get Ajax to work but the JavaScript code is not sending the form data.

Can you please help or help me to debug this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not sending any data to the server. Try to add the data as a second parameter to the function.

```
// get the text from the input field with the id "email"
var email = $.("#email").val();
// get the url from the form
var url = $("#newsletter-send").attr('action');

$.post( url, { email: email }, function( data ) {
    // The code that you want to execute after sending the ajax call
}, "json");
```

Please do not copy paste the code but try to find the reasoning behind it. You might need to check the `url` variable to make sure you are posting to the right place. Also try to add an id attribute to the input field that contains the email.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: i am posting to the right place, i get custom error meesage

Comment: if i add email variable  to .post, data is posted to the script, but the browser page goes white, means it goes directly to my php page, here ajax fails

Comment: the same code is working for another form, i dont know why it fails here

Comment: i have put id tag on all field, still no help, its not working

Comment: i fixed it, i changed the jquery to -

Comment: $.post($(this).attr('action'),$this.serialize(), function(data) {

Comment: @rkl2020 I was reading that the form.submit() method is a handler for when you submit the form. Perhaps it is better to have an input button instead of a submit button. That way you so not change the page but instead you can post only the data to the server. In any case, I am glad that you fixed your code. If my answer helped you, would you mind upvoting it please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var form = $('#main-news-contact-form');
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent submitting the form 

    $this = $(this);

    $.post($this.attr('action'), $this.serialize()).done(function(data) {
        // Do something with data
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(15000).fadeOut();
    }, 'json');
});
```